# Can't get the LibVlcSharp UWP Sample to work with local media

Tags: libvlc, libvlcsharp

I downloaded Libvlcsharp-3.x and ran the Uwp sample(Vs2017) and it worked.  However when I changed the media source to a local file and the 'FromType' to FromType.FromPath it runs but no video and no sound. My Solution Configuration=Debug and Solution Platform=x86.  What am I missing.  Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at the logs. setting -vv in the LibVLC constructor increases the verbosity. Ilm not a UWP expert, but since all the apps are packaged, isn't there something to add to the manifest to add access to the file system, as it's the case for Android projects?

Comment: Logs and code please.

Comment: cube45: This is how I am adding the -vv option.
string[] options = eventArgs.SwapChainOptions;
Array.Resize(ref options, options.Length + 1);
options[options.Length - 1] = "-vv";
LibVLC = new LibVLC(options);

Assuming this is correct, where would I find the log file?  What is it called?

Comment: mfkl, After I figure out logging I will get back to you with 'logs and code'. Thanks.

Comment: new LibVLC("--verbose=2"); and LibVLC.Log += ...

Comment: mfkl, Thanks.  After seeing the word 'permission' in the log it caused change my Package.appxmanifest file and the Windows 10 File System settings specific to my app.  All better now.